# Error code one when trying to install python module

Tags: python, github, pip

after command pip install spotify-ripper

```
Command "/Users/ink/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import     
setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x4/6m1qwdmx7x9_qsbwv4zsny6w0000gn/T
/pip-build-oQ_7kB/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',      
open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /var/folders/x4/6m1qwdmx7x9_qsbwv4zsny6w0000gn/T/pip-
3YzrfM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in     
/private/var/folders/x4/6m1qwdmx7x9_qsbwv4zsny6w0000gn/T/pip-build-
oQ_7kB/cffi/
```

also this is pretty important

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: 'ffi.h' file not found
#include <ffi.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Check that you have installed libffi and libffi-dev.

Comment: You need to install the development headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982486/glib-compile-error-ffi-h-but-libffi-is-installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the include files for `libffi` cannot be located by the compiler.

It appears that you are using OSX.  If `xcode` has been installed correctly then you should have include files at `/usr/include/ffi`.

If so, try:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ffi pip install spotify-ripper
```

(If you are using `macports` or `homebrew` you may find it easier to install their version of `libffi`)

Comment: still didn't work. What's libffi? xcode has been successfully installed as far as I can tell.

EDIT: just installed libffi from homebrew and it works, thanks!